# Change default view on sharepoint blog

Tags: blog

I am trying to figure out how to have only certain categories of blog posts show on the default page of the blog.

Any time I create a new view or modify existing views the default page does not show up formatted as a blog entry but rather as the list.

Any help would be appreciated.
Ken

Answer (score 2):

The summary view doesn't show up when you edit posts.  You need to modify the view associated with the blog widget.  I stumbled on the following and it does the job.

1. On main blog page select Site Actions -> Edit Page.
2. On "Posts" widget select Edit -> Modify Shared Web Part.
3. Under selected view there is a drop down but also just below that a link "edit the current view".
   Click this link and apply a filter based on the categories you want to view.

The view only affects the blog widget and not the individual category views which appear to be individually editable in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I'd tried that but following your sequence did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

CWQP + XSLT would be my approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you take away all occurrences of the "ddwrt:ghost=hide" line in your default.aspx page of the blog, you'll be able to customize the page. Basically that will unghost the page from the default template so you can make changes. Then you should be able to do whatever you want. You can always reghost the file by right clicking on the default.aspx file in SPD and selecting "reset to site template" or something (forgot exact wording)

Answer (score -1):

Just in case you don't have designer access, you can always add a web part below the post on the display view that only shows the additional columns you wish to see and that is "connected to" the post's webpart and getting filtered values from it.  Connect to the Title field.

Comment: How does this help the poster prevent categories of blog posts from appearing?